# Testing a module in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a module that looks like this:

```
module FileTypeProcessor
  def self.read(input_path:, with_headers: nil, return_headers: nil)
    raise MethodNotImplementedError
  end

  def self.write(output_path:, data:)
    raise MethodNotImplementedError
  end
end
```

and this is how I'm trying to test it:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FileTypeProcessor do
  let(:dummy_class) { Class.new { extend FileTypeProcessor } }
  let(:input_path) { "some/input/path/file.csv" }
  let(:output_path) { "some/output/path/file.csv" }
  let(:data) { ['some', 'arbitrary', 'data'] }

  describe ".read" do
    subject { dummy_class.read(input_path: input_path) }

    it "raises an error if unimplemented" do
      expect{ subject }.to raise_error(MethodNotImplementedError)
    end
  end
```

But i'm still getting this when I run it:

```
expected MethodNotImplementedError, got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `read' for #<Class:0x00007fd2820dc3f0>> with backtrace:
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I write a dummy class that extends this module so I can see that it does indeed raise an error when unimplemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `self.` from the module.

```
module FileTypeProcessor
  def read(input_path: nil, with_headers: nil, return_headers: nil)
    raise MethodNotImplementedError
  end
end

Class.new { extend FileTypeProcessor }.read # => MethodNotImplemented
```

If you want to be able to call the methods through the module, you must mark them as public module functions:

```
module FileTypeProcessor
  def read(input_path: nil, with_headers: nil, return_headers: nil)
    raise MethodNotImplementedError
  end
  module_function :read
  public :read
end

FileTypeProcessor.read # => MethodNotImplemented
Class.new { extend FileTypeProcessor }.read # => MethodNotImplemented
Class.new { include FileTypeProcessor }.new.read # => MethodNotImplemented
```